# How to change unread emails settings in evolution

Tags: evolution

Is it possible to change the settings of unread email so that it's displayed in red if the email is unread and black if otherwise?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That might be done via "[theming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_%28computing%29)". Evolution seems to use the [GTK3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B) toolkit, and AFAIK one can have special definitions per-app with a given style.

Taking a look at the last Wikipedia page linked, there seem to be some [GUI designers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B#GUI_designers) available which should help you creating/modifying a theme. But be aware that still, despite of those GUI helpers, it's not a "simple task" -- and due to lack of experience I cannot guide you to do that "with a few clicks".

AFAIK there's no way to change that from within Evolution itself.